# Rails 3.2 - validate format of date

Tags: ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the model `Teacher` which has field `:teacher_birthday`. I get `:teacher_birthday` from the view (a single textbox). I want to make sure that an input date has a such format - `dd.mm.yyyy` (i mean i want to be sure, that an input date  as `12.24.1991` will not be save in db because such date is wrong) and that this date exists. Also, i want to do this in the MODEL. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try the **[chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic)** gem. It has very flexible date parsing, including what you're looking for:

```
[11] pry(main)> require 'chronic'
=> true
[12] pry(main)> Chronic.parse('24.12.1991'.gsub('.','-'))
=> 1991-12-24 12:00:00 -0700
```

Comment: And how can i validate my date using that? I don't understand. I don't know how to get input string before it becomes date in db.

Comment: @ExR, I suggest parsing your date with Chronic, and then just validating that it's not nil. That's not what you asked for, but it gives users a lot more flexibility on how to input their dates.

Comment: It's bad that there is no good solution for what i need so much... It looks like i will use controller and add errors in that (i hate such my method, anyway).

Comment: @Mori did you find a better solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the validation method to be called in your model, and then define this method. The following should roughly do what you need:

```
validate :validate_teacher_birthday

private

def validate_teacher_birthday
  errors.add("Teacher birthday", "is invalid.") unless (check_valid_date && valid_date_format)
end

def valid_date_format
  self.teacher_birthday.match(/[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/)
end

def check_valid_date
  begin
    parts = self.teacher_birthday.split(".") #contains array of the form [day,month,year]
    Date.civil(parts[2].to_i,parts[1].to_i,parts[0].to_i)
  rescue ArgumentError
    #ArgumentError is thrown by the Date.civil method if the date is invalid
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: I try your code and after that i get a lot of errors in rspec, for example: `Failure/Error: @user.create_teacher( @attr_teacher )
          NoMethodError:
          undefined method split for Wed, 31 Dec 1980:Date`. Also when i visit my page and i try to print invalid date after submit  i get `undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Also, when i print a correct date in my form i get: `undefined method split for Sun, 01 Dec 1991:Date`